# What DirectX components are retained in Windows 8 SDK?

Tags: windows, directx

**Background**: I've developing in Visual Studio 2013 and targeting .Net 4.5, running on Windows 7.   I've been trying to get DirectX to run in a WPF context and was referred to SharpDX, and to a sample program using it:  http://sharpdxwpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#SharpDX.WPF.sln

When I tried to build it I got errors because 'd3dcompiler_43.dll' was missing.   I fixed that by explicitly downloading the DirectX End User Runtimes (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8109)

**My Question**:   According to MSDN DirectX has been folded into the Windows 8 SDK (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/03/22/where-is-the-directx-sdk/), and according to the same document it is included with Visual Studio 2012.

Since I'm using VS2013 (Professional) I assumed that it's also included in that.  So why did I have to explicitly download the DirectX End User package to get my DLL?  Or does the Windows 8 SDK not include legacy DLL's?  (and if so, how are legacy programs supposed to work in Windows 8 and 10?)     Could someone please explain the DirectX roadmap in practical terms to me?

Comment: It is an awkward DLL, the shader compiler is not part of the DirectX runtime and should only be deployed in the same directory as the EXE that uses it.  Note that the _43 version is old.  What you are *supposed* to do is use the copy that came with the SDK.  That gets murky with a wrapper like SharpDX because it doesn't need the SDK.

Comment: @Hans_Passant So Hans, is there a non-murky way to get hardware acceleration of 3D lines in a WPF context?  WPF has no native 3D line primitive and all the alternatives seem to be unsupported or 3rd-party hobby projects (SlimDX, SharpDX, Helix3D, etc) using deprecated DirectX/Direct3D DLLs.  I'm a contract engineer on a short-term assignment and I'd like to leave my client with something they can maintain that doesn't depend on deprecated or unsupported 3rd party components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The story around D3DCompile is told [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile/).

In short, building with the SharpDX package doesn't require you have the legacy DirectX SDK installed, but you do need the old optional side-by-side DLLs it deployed. You can get the old #43 version by installing [DXSETUP](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2011/04/19/dxsetup-update/).

> See [Not So DirectSetup](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2010/09/08/not-so-direct-setup/) for all the details on the legacy DirectX SDK component deployment.

For modern apps using Direct 11 or DirectX 12, you'd be better off using D3DCompile #47. It's built into the Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 OS, the headers are in the Windows 8.1 SDK, and there's a redistable DLL in the Windows 8.1 SDK that you can use for Windows Vista SP2 or later 'side-by-side' deployed with your app. SharpDX should probably be using that one, but they are likely sticking with #43 in case you want to support Windows XP.

> For a full list of the DLLs that were deployed by the legacy DirectX SDK and DXSETUP, see [KB179113](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/179113). None of these are deployed by the Windows SDK nor are any of them included with any version of the Windows OS.

Comment: But I thought that WPF's D3DImage didn't support anything higher than DirectX 9.     So I can't use those with WPF, right?  As Hans said, this whole thing is murky and I'm only a part-time contractor and I'd like to leave my client with an **un-**murky solution because they're going to be stuck maintaining it.

Comment: Unless your system requirements include Windows XP, I'd suggest using DirectX11 with [WPFDXInterop](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPFDXInterop). If you want to stick with DirectX9 you can, but probably requires you use the legacy DirectX SDK in some fashion.